# Wordpress 3.5 and Galleries

Tags: wordpress, mobile, sliders

I am some difficulty working with the new galleries in WordPress 3.5. Here is a brief description of the problem we are having.

**Project Details**

Desktop and Mobile site generated from the same WP install

Currently using a modified version of swipe http://swipejs.com/ for a mobile slider that supports getting more post attachments with an offset

**What we require**

A way to embed the same gallery on multiple pages

Picture listing type gallery for Desktop site

Slider Gallery for mobile that support swiping, display one image at a time when swiped will get another image with ajax and display it

**Problems**

Wordress 3.5 no longer attaches images for galleries, cannot use get post attachments to get images used in gallery

Tried nextgen gallery but can't find a way to have more than 2 image sizes for a gallery, we would need a desktop thumbnail, the original image, and a mobile sized image

Any suggestions how to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you upload to a post it will still set that relation. There is a option to display 'images uploaded to this post' in the gallery. in the media manager. SO I don't know what you mean with:

> cannot use get post attachments

What code are / where you using to display the gallery?

Comment: In wordpress 3.5 the galleries are generated using [gallery ids="729,732,731,720"] If you select a image from your image gallery it is not attached to the post. I was using `$args = array(
     'post_parent' => 283, 
     'post_status' => 'inherit', 
     'post_type' => 'attachment', 
     'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
     'order' => 'ASC', 
     'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
     'numberposts'     => 2,
     'offset'          => 0
    );
 
    $spa_tour_images = get_children( $args );`

Answer (score 0):

Till 3.5 You could get all attachments images id with:

```
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
```

where $post_id is an id of current post, $order and $order_by are standard query variables (ASC, menu_order in standard)

Then with images ID You can get them all using foreach and calling:

```
wp_get_attachment_link
```

to get a link to image, or to get completly html img  code with alts, widths etc:

```
 wp_get_attachment_image
```

Should work well in 3.5, so You could upload all images to one post and use it as a placeholder for displaying entire gallery anywhere.

Comment: The problem with this method is if a user selects an existing image from the image gallery, it will not get attached to the post. When referencing the gallery by post id, only the images attached to that post will show.